# Asynchronously load a Vue plugin

Tags: vue.js, plugins, nuxt.js

For my project, I'm using [Buefy](https://buefy.org/documentation/constructor-options) and I only install the plugins I need before init my Vue app.

```
import { Modal, Rate } from 'buefy'
Vue.use(Modal);
Vue.use(Rate);
```

But to improve performances I would like to asynchronously load these plugins. Like I'm doing for some components (cf below), but I can't find how I can do that with [plugins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html).

```
await import('~/components/forms/FormContact.vue');
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Even if you find a way to import the JS, the biggest and heaviest part will still be the CSS. Looked for it a few days but found out that the CSS of Buefy(/bulma) is one single big block that you need to load as is right away.

Comment: Indeed but I'm using PurgeCSS to clean the CSS :)

Comment: If you can achieve to make it work, perfect my mate ! :D

Answer (score 1):

From the [official docs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/plugins/):

> The plugins directory contains JavaScript plugins that you want to run before instantiating the root Vue.js Application.

I know that you can customize the behavior of a plugin when you do create it thanks to some helpers like [nuxtState](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/internals-glossary/context#nuxtstate).
And even change, the [behavior of the plugins](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-extend-plugins/) but it at the end, if you look at the [lifecycle of Nuxt](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/concepts/nuxt-lifecycle), it will always be loaded before any lazy loading logic that you may implement.

So, I'm pretty sure it cannot be done right now. At least, the documentation goes into that direction. May be interesting to ask it on Discord to have an official confirmation.